# Xcode 10: Multiple command produce [CP] Embed Pods Framework

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, sdk, xcode10

There are a lot of questions and answers for this problem on stack overflow. I'm using Jumio Mobile SDK which encountered this problem. One solution that I've tried is by selecting "Copy only when installing" option under Embed Frameworks.

Can anyone confirm this solution won't affect the functionality enabled by the framework in question? Anyone tried this solution in their project? I'm unable to test it.

Answer (score 7):

If anyone still has problems with this, one solution that worked great is to

Run `pod deintegrate` in terminal
then run `pod install` or `pod update`

For some reason my project got "corrupted" and deintegrating and installing again regenerated the project and everything worked.

Comment: Worked for me! Thank you so much!

Comment: You're a genius!

Comment: It worked in Xcode 11 with deployment targer iOS 11! This should be the selected answer!

Answer (score 6):

These possible solutions may work.

**Workaround 1:**

Open `yourProject.xcworkspace`

Select the Project target and then select the Build Phases tab.

Expand the `Embed Frameworks` phase and select  `Jumio Mobile SDK` from the embedded frameworks list.

Click `-` to remove `Jumio Mobile SDK` from the list

**Workaround 2:**

Open your workspace project, then navigate to `File -> Workspace Settings` and change the `build system` to `Legacy Build System`.

Comment: for workaround 1, once I removed it, the app will crash upon running it. specifically, its not the whole mobile SDK that is in the framework list. only some of the framework from Jumio Mobile SDK is used.

for workaround 2, it works but what I've read this is only suppressing the error so its not a long term fix.

Any long term fix for this?

Answer (score 2):

I came to this question finding a solution for the same problem but, in my case, I was using Streamroot which also contains a dSYM.

I had the following error in my Test target:

```
Multiple commands produce '/Users/ramonharomarques/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WhiteLabel-fxmmcdtjlibmcxeakswrahwfxrqj/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/StreamrootSDK.framework.dSYM':
1) That command depends on command in Target 'HistoryHit' (project 'WhiteLabel'): script phase “[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks”
2) That command depends on command in Target 'TVPlayer' (project 'WhiteLabel'): script phase “[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks”
3) That command depends on command in Target 'WhiteLabel' (project 'WhiteLabel'): script phase “[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks”
```

Turns out I had in my Target - Build Phase - Dependencies 2 extra app targets using the same framework.
[image]

By removing the 2 extra targets, everything worked smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered it after I added `Swinject` to multiple targets. To fix it, I tried to run `gem update cocoapods` to `1.7.5` and the issue is no more.